# .htaccess rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I have created a custom post type called 'event' and added an event called London 2012. I want the following URL structure for a page:

```
local.mysite.com/london-2012/speakers
```

I have created a page called Speakers giving me a working `/speakers` url (I have Permalinks set to 'Post name').

Now I created a static test site and added the following to the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/speakers?$ /speakers.php [NC,L]
```

This meant that if I went to `local.testsite.com/something/speakers` it would display the content of speakers.php whilst retaining the orignal URL. Perfect! Or so I thought...

Now, having migrated the rule across to my Wordpress install (both by adding the rule in the .htaccess file directly - under the `RewriteEngine on` line - and through the `add_rewrite_rule()` function) I am getting strange behaviour.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/speakers/?$ /speakers?event=%1 [L]
```

Instead of the URL remaining the same and showing me the content of `/speakers`, it is actually redirecting me to the /speakers page and the URL is changing.

This is default behavior for a page in WP even without any modifications to the .htaccess file so I can only imagine that it is not matching my rule for some reason and then hitting the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` line. Either that, or it is matching it but then continuing despite the `[L]` line.

Anyway I think that covers everything - if anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate it as I'm going a bit crazy with this!

**Update 1**

Sorted - thanks Brian. Your solution did work but because the query variable was called 'event' it was getting confused and sending me to /speakers/ as a redirect. I changed it to simply be 'e' and it's fine now. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you followed the page load redirect by redirect, for example, with WireShark or HttpFox? I suspect you have more than one redirect happening.

Comment: Multi-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966134/wordpress-htaccess-rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to process the rewrite using query strings rather than a URI segment and pass your query through index.php. WordPress seems to be agnostic of what you're trying to accomplish here.

Try the following rule and visit your Settings->Permalinks page to flush previous rules and add this to the stack.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/speakers/?$', //Checked against the global $wp object - $wp->request
    'index.php?page=speakers&event=$matches[1]', //Use WP_Query params to find your page
    'top' //This will superceed the default WP rewrite stack
);
```

Make sure to register your query variable as well with WP so you can use it within `$wp_query`;

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query_vars');
function my_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'event';
    return $vars;
}
```

You can then access your `event` query variable using the following:

```
get_query_var('event');
```

For testing, I'm very fond of the [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) plugin. It allows you to see behind the curtain of WordPress rewrites and assess which rules are matches, and how their query strings are fleshed out.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response Brian. 

Acccording to Monkey Analyser it's now hitting the redirect correctly:

^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/speakers/?$ 
           page: speakers
          event: ([A-Za-z0-9-]+)

HOWEVER the page it is showing isn't showing and post.

Comment: 'HOWEVER the page it is showing isn't showing' sorry a bit confused by this. Do you mean you're getting a 404 error?

Comment: Hi Brian, I've updated the original question with my findings. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Forgot to accept this but this ended up being a great solution, thanks Brian.